# Mismatched types: `expected fn@(&&@type) -> uint` but found `extern fn(@map_a) -> uint` (expected argument mode ++ but found &&)

Tags: types, rust

```
$ rustc --test mapAsMapKey.rs 
mapAsMapKey.rs:18:43: 18:52 error: mismatched types: expected `fn@(&&@map_a) -> uint` but found `extern fn(@map_a) -> uint` (expected argument mode ++ but found &&)
mapAsMapKey.rs:18     let b: map_b = hashmap::<@map_a, uint>(rmap_hash, rmap_eqer);
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~
mapAsMapKey.rs:18:54: 18:63 error: mismatched types: expected `fn@(&&@map_a, &&@map_a) -> bool` but found `extern fn(@map_a, @map_b) -> bool` (expected argument mode ++ but found &&)
mapAsMapKey.rs:18     let b: map_b = hashmap::<@map_a, uint>(rmap_hash, rmap_eqer);
                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

The rust functions:

```
fn rmap_hash (m: @map_a) -> uint { 0 }
fn rmap_eqer (m1: @map_a, m2: @map_b) -> bool { true }
```

The line triggering:

```
let b: map_b = hashmap::<@map_a, uint>(rmap_hash, rmap_eqer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you write the Rust functions like this?

```
fn rmap_hash (&&m: @map_a) -> uint { 0 }

fn rmap_eqer (&&m1: @map_a, &&m2: @map_b) -> bool { true }
```

Comment: Yes. As you said on IRC. Though I'm still not sure what they are.